# Learning SwiftUI view does not update from time to time

Tags: swiftui, combine, swift-concurrency

I think I'm doing something wrong here. Problem is that when this example app is running and when I'm trying to `Reload` it can stuck randomly on loading screen and thats it. View didn't respond to any update of state again. It just displays ProgressView and that's it. I don't know even how to diagnose the problem because when I run debugger this behavior can not be replicated. Looks like some timing issues maybe related to RunLoop ticks and how/when SwiftUI update it's view.

If somebody can guide me where is the problem in my code...

Here is a ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

public final class TransactionContainerViewModel: ObservableObject {

    public enum ViewState<T> {
        case loading
        case loaded(T)
        case error(message: String)
    }

    @Published public var state: ViewState<[TransactionViewModel]> = .loading

    private var disposable: AnyCancellable?

    public typealias TransactionsPublisher = AnyPublisher<[TransactionItem], Error>

    private let loader: TransactionsPublisher

    public init(loader: TransactionsPublisher) {
        self.loader = loader
    }

    public func loadTransactions() {
        disposable?.cancel()
        state = .loading // 1

        disposable = loader.sink { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .failure:
                self?.state = .error(message: "Some error") // 2

            case .finished: break
            }
        } receiveValue: { [weak self] items in
            let sortedTransactions = items.sorted { $0.bookingDate > $1.bookingDate }
            let transactionsVM = sortedTransactions.map { item in
                TransactionViewModel(transaction: item)
            }
            self?.state = .loaded(transactionsVM) // 3
        }
    }
}
```

There are three places where `state` property can update/mutate.

Loader that is injected in init is built like that:

```
let upstreamQueue = DispatchQueue.global()
let client = createMockedHTTPClient()
let mockedLoader: AnyPublisher<[TransactionItem], Error> = client.getPublisher(url: url)
  .subscribe(on: upstreamQueue)
  .delay(for: .seconds(1), tolerance: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: upstreamQueue)
  .tryMap(TransactionsMapper.map)
  .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

The View that from time to time is not updating according to `vm.state` Published property.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TransactionContainerView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var vm: TransactionContainerViewModel

    init(viewModel: TransactionContainerViewModel) {
        self.vm = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch vm.state {
            case .loading:
                ProgressView()

            case let .loaded(transactions):
                Text("Loaded: \(transactions.count) transactions")
                Button("Reload") {
                    vm.loadTransactions()
                }

            case let .error(message):
                Text(message)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            vm.loadTransactions()
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain what can cause this to stuck at `ProgressView`? This is totally random behavior. Sometimes very time consuming to replicate and sometimes very fast. I suspect some threading issues or missing some SwiftUI ticks but I'm just learning this stuff and any help could be great.

- switching to `.loading` state always works and view updates as expected
- switching to `.error` or `.loaded` state works most of the time but it can not work from time to time. Switching to those states are async because call to `loadTransactions` was ended before.

**UPDATE:**

I found the reason what caused the problem. Loader was created with `let upstreamQueue = DispatchQueue.global()` and `global()` returns concurrent queue.

Now I know WHAT but WHY is another story. Somehow concurrent queue was problematic. I updated code that is handling subscription to loader like this just to find reason. I was thinking maybe something is calling cancel on my disposable or it is deallocated. Updated code to understand better what was going on...

```
public func loadTransactions() {
        print("loadTransactions")
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
        disposable?.cancel()

        state = .loading
        var stateDidSet = false

        disposable = loader
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { s in
                print("  receiveSubscription")
            }, receiveOutput: { output in
                print("  receiveOutput")
            }, receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print("  receiveCompletion: \(completion)")
            }, receiveCancel: {
                print("  receiveCancel")
            }, receiveRequest: { demand in
                print("  receiveRequest: \(demand)")
            })
            .sink { [weak self] result in
                switch result {
                case .failure:
                    self?.state = .error(message: Self.errorMessage)
                    stateDidSet = true
                    print("  completed with error")
                case .finished:
                    if !stateDidSet {
                        print("WARNING stateDidSet is false and we received completion")
                        self?.state = .error(message: "Unexpected error")
                    }
                    print("  completed")
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] items in
                let sortedTransactions = items.sorted { $0.bookingDate > $1.bookingDate }
                let transactionsVM = sortedTransactions.map { item in
                    TransactionViewModel(transaction: item)
                }
                self?.state = .loaded(transactionsVM)
                stateDidSet = true
                print("  loaded")
            }
    }
```

I noticed that I'm not covering one case with setting state. It was completion without error state. But I was not expecting this can complete before outputing value but I give it a try. I created `stateDidSet` variable so I can make if statement and put breakpoint there. Finally I catched this case. Completed is called but without emitting any output value. Why? I don't know but changing queue to serial fixed the problem. Does somebody know WHY?

Comment: every `ObservableObject` has to be wrapped with something. `Published` is not capable of knowing when `TransactionViewModel` changes. SwiftUI is very strict, you have to ensure that you understand `DynamicProperty` so you know how to trigger UI updates. Demystify SwiftUI can give you a good start.

Comment: Make sure `state` is updated on main thread (or make the entire `TransactionContainerViewModel` a `@MainActor` - even better)